# Exporting SVG icon from Sketch without the "?xml" tag

Tags: xml, svg, sketchapp

Is it somehow possible to export SVG icon from the Sketch without the "?xml" tag?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Why? What's the problem with the xml tag? Maybe we can fix that instead?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not; but if the XML declaration causes problems (for example because you want to concatenate multiple XML documents into a single one) then there are easy ways to solve that (for example by using XML-aware tools, such as XSLT, to do the concatenation).